# Windows Forms program suddenly closes when running a query. How do I catch the error before it stops/crashes?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, crash

I have a 3 PC setup that runs the POS-like program I created. 1 PC that acts as the server and the 2 as the client. I have a heavy query in the client-side that when executed, sometimes closes the program. How do I catch the problem before it force closes?

The query checks the remaining stocks by getting the sum of all the inputted stocks and subtracting it from the products sold, transferred to another branch and those that got damaged. So every time they search a product, it goes through 4 tables (Inventory, Sales, Transferred, Damaged) to get the stocks and 4 more tables to get the product's description (Product, Category, Subcategory, Supplier).

So going back, how do I log the error before the application closes? I'm thinking of getting the form closed event but how do I log it only if it crashes?

EDIT 1: I always put try catch with message box to all my methods. The application doesn't pop up any messages before it closes.

```
SELECT p.Id,p.Product_Name Product,p.Description,
c.Category_Name Category,sc.Subcategory_Name Subcategory,s.Supplier_Name Supplier,p.Selling_Price `Unit Price`,
i.Stocks,s.Sales,i.Stocks - IFNULL(s.Sales, 0) - IFNULL(t.Transfer, 0) - IFNULL(d.Damage, 0) AS Remaining

FROM (SELECT Id, Product_Name, Description, Selling_Price, Category_Id, Subcategory_Id, Supplier_Id FROM product WHERE enable_flag = 1) p

LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) AS Stocks FROM inventory WHERE enable_flag = 1 GROUP BY product_id) i
ON p.Id = i.product_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(quantity), 0) AS Sales FROM sales_detail WHERE enable_flag = 1 GROUP BY product_id) s
USING(product_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(transfer_quantity), 0) AS Transfer FROM stock_transfer WHERE enable_flag = 1 GROUP BY product_id) t
USING(product_id)

LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT product_id, COALESCE(SUM(damaged_quantity), 0) AS Damage FROM damaged_product WHERE enable_flag = 1 GROUP BY product_id) d
USING(product_id)

JOIN Category c ON p.Category_Id=c.Id
JOIN Subcategory sc ON p.Subcategory_Id=sc.Id
JOIN Supplier s ON p.Supplier_Id=s.Id;
```

EDIT 2:

Here's my button code (`Variables.dgvSearchItemsDataSource` is equivalent to the posted query):

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvSearchItems.DataSource = dbConnect.DatabaseToDatagrid(Variables.dgvSearchItemsDataSource + " WHERE p.Product_Name LIKE '" + cmbSrchProd.Text + "%'");
    if (dgvSearchItems.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        this.dgvSearchItems.Columns[1].Frozen = true;
        this.dgvSearchItems.Columns[2].Frozen = true;
        this.dgvSearchItems.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        this.dgvSearchItems.Columns[7].Visible = false;
        this.dgvSearchItems.Columns[8].Visible = false;
    }
    txtQuantity.Focus();
}
```

The method I use to connect to my database:

```
private bool OpenConnection()
{
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 0:
                myNotification = new frmNotifOk();
                myNotification.Show("Cannot connect to server.");
                break;

            case 1045:
                myNotification = new frmNotifOk();
                myNotification.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again.");
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What the heck, why did it got a negative point?? I'm asking a legit question and gave enough detail to it and also did a suggestion so I can get some opinions

Comment: Thanks man! I also edited my post just to clarify that I put `Try Catch` to all my methods. But it doesn't catch it when it closes

Answer (score 1):

It seems that although you think you put try/catch blocks around every call, somewhere an unhandled exception is thrown.

I think https: [System.AppDomain.UnhandledException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) might help.

> This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the application to log information about the exception before the system default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the application. If sufficient information about the state of the application is available, other actions may be undertaken — such as saving program data for later recovery

Handling this event will give you the opportunity to log the problem before the program closes.

usage:

```
static class Program
{
    private static MyLogger logger = new MyLogger();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledException;

        ...
    }

    static void UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var exc = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        if (exc != null)
        {   // log the exception
            logger.LogException(exc);
        }
        // Problem is logged, Can't continue, so quit the application:
        Environment.Exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man! This is what I've been looking for! But what's the `MyLogger` contains?

Comment: Since you wrote: "So going back, how do I log the error before the application closes?"  I thought you'd have some logging mechanism. If you don't, consider a nuget package like Common.Logging. In visual studio in your project's solution explorer (where your projects are grouped into a solution), right click References -> Manage Nuget Packages. Then Browse with search string Logging and select one of the logging packages.

Answer (score 0):

Add a try catch block around the code you are using to execute the query

```
        try
        {
            // Execute query
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
           // Exception handling
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: I always put try catch with a message box when opening and closing connections and when running queries. The fact that it didn't pop up any message before it force closes makes it hard for me to pinpoint what's wrong in the program

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to perform all the database activity?

Comment: In your code you only catch MySqlExceptions (`catch (MySqlException ex)`). Other exceptions are still unhandled. In general it is good practice to use try/catch in each event handler.